# How to set up multiple port forwarding rules?

Tags: linux, docker, squid, port-forwarding

I have recently set up multiple Squid proxy servers on my Rasp Pi 3 using Docker.

I opened ports on my router, one server is accessible from port 3134 and the other 3135, however, this requires 2 different and separate port forwarding rules on my router, in which I have a maximum limit of 20 rules. I would like to set up around 100 servers using multiple Pi's so this is a problem.

I tried using only one rule for both servers, since they are on the machine like this:

```
internal port start:3134
internal port end:3135
external port start:3134
external port end:3135
```

However, when connecting using `IP:3134` or `IP:3135` I always get connected to the server on port 3134, even when I connect to `IP:3135`.

Is there any thing I can do but open 100 rules with a different router? Any ideas?

Thanks!